# Show all running instances by month

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Would like to know if it's possible to show all running instances on a monthly basis.

I know that the following command can list all running instances across all regions, but I'm not sure how to filter by month:
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --output text

I looked at the options under --filters on this page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html

Nothing seems to allow me to filter based on past month.

I also looked at JMESPath which has additional jquery options that are already built into the AWS CLI, but couldn't find mention of filtering by month.

Short of creating a job to run the aforementioned aws cli to run on the 1st of every month and output to an S3 bucket, is there another way to grab this data for past months?

Answer (score 0):

There is a different option to address this problem. It is more sophisticated but it will help you later to get any kind of queries you are looking for. Here you go:

- Enable Detailed Billing Report from your Account Billing section inside your AWS console
- Make sure that you configure it correctly so AWS can export your billing information to S3 bucket that you specified.
- Now onboard this billing information into AWS Redshift DB by writing a lambda function that does this every day
- Download an AWS Redshift client and start querying your billing data to get the actual on/off time for any EC2 instances during anytime
- Billing data gives you how many hours any instances in your account have been working during a day so you can get which instance was on or off and for how many hours

Please let me know if you would like me to explain this process further

Comment: Thank you Ahmed.  I figured this probably couldn't be tackled by the AWS CLI.  Just wanted confirmation.  I appreciate the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a user of septaz, you can use Septaz dashboard to monitor ec2 instance costs and know details of all instances started and terminated during a month.

https://www.septaz.com

We use septaz to run production workloads using spot instances and reduce our cost by 80%.